# Can I add commas to an SVG path that doesn't have any?

Tags: svg

I've seen SVGs with commas in the `d` attribute of the path, and other that do.
The examples I provide are different SVGs, I'm just using them for the example.

```
<svg fill="#6396b1" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M20 2H4c-1.1 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L2 22l4-4h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V4c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2zM6 9h12v2H6V9zm8 5H6v-2h8v2zm4-6H6V6h12v2z"/>
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

Can I convert the one above to:

```
<svg xmlns:x="http://ns.adobe.com/Extensibility/1.0/" xmlns:i="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeIllustrator/10.0/" xmlns:graph="http://ns.adobe.com/Graphs/1.0/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="5.0 -10.0 100.0 135.0" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" height="100px" width="100px">
    <g i:extraneous="self">
        <g>
            <path fill="#132d48" d="M75.5,70.1c3-11.7,18.7-17.4,13.7-41.2C84.1,5.1,56.1,2.7,41.6,6.4c-15,3.9-27,19.9-23,33.2     c0.3,1,0.1,2.1-0.5,3c-1.8,2.8-6.8,9-8.1,12.6c-0.5,1.3,0.3,2.7,1.6,3.1c0.4,0.1,3,1.1,3.4,1.2c3.5,1.1,2.8,8.8,2.8,15.8     c0,7.3,7.8,6.3,10.3,5.8c2.6-0.6,8.3-1.1,8.3,5.9c0,0.9,0,1.7,0.1,2.3c0.1,1.4,1,2.6,2.3,3.1c5.1,2,20,5.1,38-1.4     c1.1-0.4,1.5-1.6,1-2.6C76.2,85.2,73.2,78.8,75.5,70.1z M67.9,21.1c3.6,0.5,6.1,3.8,5.5,7.4c-0.5,3.6-3.8,6.1-7.4,5.5     c-3.6-0.5-6.1-3.8-5.5-7.4C61,23.1,64.3,20.6,67.9,21.1z M54.5,63c-13.9,0-25.2-11.3-25.2-25.2c0-13.9,11.3-25.2,25.2-25.2     c2.1,0,4.2,0.3,6.2,0.8c-0.2,1.3-0.9,2.5-2,3.3c-1.7,1.3-3.8,1.4-5.6,0.5c-0.8,1-1.5,2.2-2,3.4c1.6,1.1,2.5,3.1,2.2,5.2     c-0.3,2.1-1.7,3.7-3.6,4.3c0.2,1.3,0.5,2.6,1,3.8c1.9-0.3,4,0.4,5.2,2.1c1.3,1.7,1.4,3.8,0.5,5.6c1,0.8,2.2,1.5,3.4,2     c1.1-1.6,3.1-2.5,5.2-2.2c2.1,0.3,3.7,1.7,4.3,3.6c1.3-0.2,2.6-0.5,3.8-1c-0.3-1.9,0.4-4,2.1-5.2c1.4-1,3-1.3,4.5-0.9     C79.7,51.7,68.4,63,54.5,63z"/>
            <path fill="#132d48" d="M53,42.3c-0.4-1-0.2-2.2,0.4-3c-0.4-0.5-1-1-1.5-1.5c-0.8,0.7-1.9,0.9-3,0.5c-1.1-0.4-1.7-1.4-1.8-2.4     c-0.7-0.1-1.4-0.1-2.1,0c-0.1,1.1-0.7,2-1.8,2.5c-1,0.4-2.2,0.2-3-0.4c-0.5,0.4-1,1-1.5,1.5c0.7,0.8,0.9,1.9,0.5,3     c-0.4,1.1-1.4,1.7-2.4,1.8c-0.1,0.7-0.1,1.4,0,2.1c1.1,0.1,2,0.7,2.5,1.8c0.4,1,0.2,2.2-0.4,3c0.4,0.5,1,1,1.5,1.5     c0.8-0.7,1.9-0.9,3-0.5c1.1,0.4,1.7,1.4,1.8,2.4c0.7,0.1,1.4,0.1,2.1,0c0.1-1.1,0.7-2,1.8-2.5c1-0.4,2.2-0.2,3,0.4     c0.5-0.4,1-1,1.5-1.5c-0.7-0.8-0.9-1.9-0.5-3c0.4-1.1,1.4-1.7,2.4-1.8c0.1-0.7,0.1-1.4,0-2.1C54.4,44,53.4,43.4,53,42.3z      M49.4,46.6c-0.7,1.8-2.8,2.7-4.6,2c-1.8-0.7-2.7-2.8-2-4.6c0.7-1.8,2.8-2.7,4.6-2C49.2,42.7,50.1,44.8,49.4,46.6z"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @BenVoigt Certain platforms accepted it, others did not (Xamarin didn't, Chrome did). Another question, what are the differences between the two svgs I providede?

Answer (score 0):

You can add at most one comma between any two numbers. Commas are not permitted elsewhere so M, 3, 3 is invalid for instance. You can use that comma to replace the space that would otherwise be required to separate distinct numbers.